# Concept. Calling method from the view. Error handling

Tags: python, django

My apologies, couldn't come up with better title for the question, please hear me out.

I wrote a view where I send an email after creation of an instance, and it's working as expected (ba dum tss)

```
def my_view(request):
# some code
# notify_by_email code
# some more code
```

Now I'm thinking it about an extraction of `notify_by_email` to the separate method `notify_by_email(new_instance)`. I'm thinking about doing so for several reasons: a) `notify_by_email` section of the code clutters the `view` and decreases readability and b) I have a feeling I might be using the method in another view, which would violate DRY.

Anyways, now I'm here

```
def my_view(request):
# some code
notify_by_email(new_instance)
# some more code
```

Now I'm thinking about error handling and don't want the whole view to fall if email can't be send (or whatever else method does - I'm curious about the concept). Now we need the `try-block`, right?

Should I have `try-block` within the view:

```
def my_view(request):
# some code
try:
  notify_by_email(new_instance)
except SomeException:
  pass
# some more code
```

or call the method regardless and do error handling within the method itself?

I do not know if this question is more `Python`ic or `Django`ish... Is there a flaw in my logic? Is there a conceptual difference (right/wrong way) between the approaches? Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common saying is to throw exceptions early and catch exceptions late. The former part of the saying is pretty straight forward, but the latter part isn't.

If you threw your exceptions as late as possible, all your exception handling would be done at the top most level. That'd get pretty ugly. Instead, I propose something more along the lines of:

- Handle it late enough that the method's usage doesn't become specialised due to the exception handling. (e.g. you use `notify_by_email` in two locations, one of which you don't care about handling the exception, so you just handle it directly in the method and skip the exception; then somewhere else you want the exception, but you can't use it, thanks to your exception handling in the method.)
- Handle it late enough that you have a high enough scope to sufficiently deal with your exception. If you need to alert the user of a GUI program that the email failed, and your function doesn't have access to the functions required to draw the alert, you need to raise the scope.
- Don't wait longer than you have to. Once you have the handling high enough that you're not specialising your functions, and you have the sufficient scope, that's a good place to do it.
- Code structure is a lot like art. It's subjective, and sometimes you have break the rules when you feel it's be an improvement.

If you have a method `send_email(address, contents)`, and all it has in its scope is the attributes required to send an email, then handling the exception there wouldn't be very useful unless you just wanted to move on, ignoring the problem. If you wanted display a message on your program's interface, you would need access to the functions necessary to display such, which you don't have.

Now, I'm not familiar with Django, so I don't know what a `view` is in this context, but it sounds like it has to do with displaying things. If that's the case, then `my_view` would be high enough to properly handle the exception. Now, if your `notify_by_email` method displays a message saying it succeeded, then that would be the appropriate place to handle the exception and display your error, since that would mean it has the scope necessary.

If the exception's not a huge issue, and you just want to move on, so you decide to write a log file, then you deal with it right on the spot. Whether that means writing the file right then and there, or appending the message to a variable with other possible messages and writing it later.

For much more in-depth input and discussion, there's also this post [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late)

Comment: your detailed response is highly appreciated.